# Got promise not working

Tags: parse-platform, promise

I'm trying to use promise to get in promise2

But if I have an object Widgets with several elements in it...

Why can't I have been able to get my console.log's output

```
Parse.Cloud.define("extract", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.params.user;
    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
    [...]
    }).then(function() {

        return query.find().then(function(results) {  
            _.each(results, function(result) {
                [...]


                Widget.objectId = result.id;
                Widgets[timestamp] = Widget;
            });
            return promise;
        }).then(function(results) {    

            for (var key in Widgets) {
                var Widget = Widgets[key];
                var widget_data =  Widgets[key].widget_data;
                var promise2 = Parse.Promise.as();    
                promise2 = promise2.then(function() {    
                 return Parse.Cloud.run('extractWidgetData', {
                        'widget_data': widget_data,
                    }).then(function(newresult) {
                        Widgets[key].data = newresult.data;

                        console.log('--------WHY NOT HERE ALL TIME ?--------');                              
                    });
                });

                return promise2;
            }
        }).then(function() {                
            response.success(Widgets);
            },
            function(error) {
                response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            });
    });
});
```

I'm becoming crazy to run this damn Code

**EDIT** : I finally followed Roamer's advices to implement something but I'm not sure if it's the good way to work with Promise in series...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("extract", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.params.user;
    var Widgets = {};
    ...
    ... .then(function() {
        return query.find().then(function(results) {
            return Parse.Promise.when(results.map(function(result) {
                var Widget  = ...;//some transform of `result`
                Widget.id = ...;//some transform of `result`
                var timestamp = createdAtDate.getTime();
                ...
                return Parse.Cloud.run('extractData', {
                    'widget_data': Widget.widget_data,
                }).then(function(newresult) {
                    Widget.stat = newresult.stats;
                    return Widget;//<<<<<<< important! This ensures that results.map() returns an array of promises, each of which delivers a Widget objects.
                });                                
            }));
    }).then(function() {              
        var promisedWidget = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);       
        return Parse.Promise.when(promisedWidget.map(function(Widget) {
            return Parse.Cloud.run('getWineStats', {
                'id': Widget.data.id
            }).then(function(stat) {
                Widget.stat = stat;
                return Widget;
            });                
        }));
    }).then(function() {               
        var promisedWidget = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments); 

        _.each(promisedWidget, function(Widget) {            
            var createdAtObject = Widget.createdAt;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            var strDate = createdAtObject.toString();
            var createdAtDate = new Date(strDate);
            timestamp = createdAtDate.getTime();
            Widgets[timestamp] = Widget;
        });   

        return Widgets;            
    }).then(function(Widgets) {               
                response.success(Widgets);
            },
            function(error) {
                response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            });
    });            

});
```

Comment: What is that first `[...]`? It looks like by omitting some code there you messed up indentation/matching parenthesis. Please fix that, or we won't be able to help you with your code.

Comment: Where does that `promise` come from that you `return` in that `query.find().then()` callback? What is it resolved with? Is it the same as that `var promise = Parse.Promise.as();`?

Comment: Do you get any error? Up to where does the code execute as expected?

Comment: No error, just the code as promise2 is not executed all the times. Just "time to time"

Comment: Maybe `Parse.Cloud.run('extractWidgetData', …)` does reject the promise? Or maybe there is not even the single `key` in `Widgets`?

Answer (score 1):

First, I echo Bergi's comment on indentation/matching parenthesis.

But ignoring that for a moment, at the heart of the code you have `return query.find().then(...).then(...).then(...)` but the flow from the first `.then()` to the second is incorrect. Besides which, only two .then()s are necessary as the code in the first then is synchronous, so can be merged with the second.

Delete the two lines above `for (var key in Widgets) {` then at least `Widgets` will be available to be processed further.

Going slightly further, you should be able to do all the required processing of `results` in a single loop. There seems to be little pont in building `Widgets` with `_.each(...)` then looping through the resulting object with `for (var key in Widgets) {...}`.

In the single loop, you probably want a `Parse.Promise.when(results.map(...))` pattern, each turn of the map returning a *promise of a Widget*. This way, you are passing the required data down the promise chain rather than building a `Widgets` object in an outer scope.

Do all this and you will end up with something like this :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("extract", function(request, response) {
    var user = request.params.user;
    ...
    ... .then(function() {
        return query.find().then(function(results) {
            return Parse.Promise.when(results.map(function(result) {
                var Widget  = ...;//some transform of `result`
                ...
                return Parse.Cloud.run('extractWidgetData', {
                    'widget_data': Widget.widget_data,
                }).then(function(newresult) {
                    Widget.data = newresult.data;
                    return Widget;//<<<<<<< important! This ensures that results.map() returns an array of promises, each of which delivers a Widget objects.
                });
            }));
        }).then(function() {
            //Here, compose the required Widgets array from this function's arguments
            var Widgets = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);//Yay, we got Widgets
            response.success(Widgets);
        }, function(error) {
            response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roamer, I need a rest, but will give you feedback and vote once your solution tested.

Comment: Yeah, there's still some work to do but the general pattern should be about right.